# Get Social Media Buttons (Facebook, Twitter etc) responsive

Tags: css, button, share, social-media

I am trying to get the standard buttons from Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, LinkedIn, Xing and Google+ responsive. They are too small and will not get bigger. I tried media queries and other things but it will not work.

On this site: http://www.kaufda.de/info/konsum-in-echtzeit/ they achieved it. But I cant get the solution.

For example, this is the Facebook button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

With the following script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`
```

(This is the standard Facebook like/share button)

Anyone here with a solution or the same problem?

Comment: please provide more information like css or any demo of your code as much data possible you have?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the html code you can just style it with css:

**css**

```
.fb-like {
    /* will set its width to 70% of its container */
    width: 70%;
}
```